# How to make button and ion-title inline in ion-navbar in Ionic 3?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I need to show `ion-button` and `ion-title` same line in `ion-navbar` in ion-header. Below is my code.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

How to show `ion-button` and `ion-title` **inline** in `ion-navbar` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-buttons left>
        <button ion-button icon-only >
          <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title text-left>Home</ion-title> 
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

It is working properly.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest Ionic (v5), the button position has changed to "slot" as shown below:

```
<ion-header>   
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>My Navigation Bar</ion-title>   
  </ion-toolbar> 
</ion-header>
```

Additionally, there is a new [ion-back-button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button) which inserts a back button based on the history stack, etc.

Slot values are documented here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/buttons

Header documentation here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/header

Comment: I have been struggling a bit on this after migration from 3. Thanks for saving some time

Answer (score 0):

you should use `<ion-row>` and `<ion-col>` labels. Use this:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
  <ion-row>
   <ion-col col-5>
    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button icon-only >
        <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
   </ion-col>
   <ion-col col-5>
    <ion-title text-left>Home</ion-title>
   </ion-col>
  </ion-row> 
</ion-navbar>
```

It is really important use that to do your app responsive.